# Source Safe Command line - Get all changed files since label

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, sourcesafe-6.0, vssget

I would like to do a 'GET' (From the command line, ss.exe) of files that has been added/changed since a label, and place them in say C:\temp\db

1. I have files a.cs, b.cs, c.cs currently
2. If I label my project version1.0
3. then add files 10.cs,11.cs,12.cs and 13.cs

I would like my GET to get 10, 11, 12 and 13...

Let me know if this is possible!

I have tried:

```
ss GET "$/xyz/parentproject/project" -GLc:\temp\db\ -Vl~"proj 3.2.27" -I-N
```

Comment: Why you didnt you try from VSS editor tool which is provided by Microsoft.